# Netbeans Code Completion pops up too often in C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, drop-down-menu, code-completion

I'm having issues using netbeans code completion.

Whenever I am at the end of a line (either a ';' or a '{', depending on context), the code completion box pops up. This causes an issue because after typing

```
else {
```

or

```
int testValue;
```

etc, etc, I want to press enter to go to the next line. But because of the code completion, when I press enter, it inserts one of the variables I have declared earlier.

Is there a way to make the code completion smarter so that it won't pop up in those instances?

Answer (score 1):

Check vlues under: "Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion".
The default value  for Auto Popup Triggers for C/C++ Identifier is:

```
.;->;.*;->*;::;new ;
```

[image: The default value for Auto Popup Triggers for C/C++ Identifier]
Check the value in your configuration if it contains Two consecutive semi colons

```
;;
```

or a closing curly braces

```
}
```

and remove them. If you want the most code completion with no completion at ends use:

```
.;->;.*;->*;::;new ;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O;P;Q;R;S;T;U;V;W;X;Y;Z;
```

Otherwise revert to the default value mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth taking a look at the "Code Completion" options, you can find this under **"Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion"**.

I'm not sure if it has an option to set the timer for code completion for C++. However, there are a variety of options there which may help you. You can completely turn it off if you like.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've looked in there, but it doesn't allow for changing the behavior in specific instances like I mentioned. I don't really want a delay added, I just want it to not pop up in those instances.

Comment: @JoshJohnson In that case, I'm not sure it's possible in Netbeans at the moment.